# How to apply filters property in redux-toolkit in ReactJS projects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

[image]I want to filter property in my shopping cart websites. I am using here redux-toolkit in my ReactJS projects. I displayed the products. I am using here (https://dummyjson.com/products) API to list my products in my project. I want to apply the filter property of category and prices. I tried it but the filtering function is not applying. Kindly help me how to apply and make filter property in redux-toolkit in Reactjs. Below are all the files of the code.

productSlice.js

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
const baseURL = "https://dummyjson.com/products";
export const STATUSES = Object.freeze({
  IDLE: "idle",
  ERROR: "error",
  LOADING: "loading",
});

export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  "products/fetch",
  async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(baseURL);
    const data = await res.data;
    return data;
  }
);

export const getProduct = createAsyncThunk(
  "product/getProduct",
  async (id, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`${baseURL}/${id}`);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.response);
    }
  }
);




const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: "product",
  initialState: {
    products: [],
    product: {},
    status: STATUSES.IDLE,
  },
  reducers: {
   
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchProducts.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = STATUSES.LOADING;
      })
      .addCase(fetchProducts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.products = action.payload;
        state.status = STATUSES.IDLE;
      })
      .addCase(fetchProducts.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = STATUSES.ERROR;
      })
      .addCase(getProduct.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = STATUSES.LOADING;
      })

      .addCase(getProduct.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = STATUSES.IDLE;
        state.product = action.payload;
      });
  },
});

export const { handlePriceFilter } = productSlice.actions;
export default productSlice.reducer;
```

Home.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Products, SearchBar } from "../components";
import Filters from "../components/Filters";
import { fetchProducts, STATUSES } from "../redux/features/productSlice";
import { FaFilter } from "react-icons/fa";
import SidebarFilterPanel from "../components/SidebarFilterPanel";
const categories = [
  "Smartphones",
  "Laptops",
  "Fragrances",
  "Skincare",
  "Groceries",
  "Home-Decoration",
];
const Home = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { products, status } = useSelector((state) => state.product.products);

  const [openFilter, setOpenFilter] = useState(false);
  const openFilterPanel = () => setOpenFilter(!openFilter);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "Shoping Website";
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex gap-4 justify-between px-4">
        <div className="hidden md:block">
          <Filters categories={categories} />
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full">
          <div className="flex items-center">
            <SearchBar />
            <div
              onClick={openFilterPanel}
              className={`bg-black text-white py-[10px] px-3 md:hidden block rounded cursor-pointer ml-2 mt-3 duration-1000 transition-all`}
            >
              <FaFilter onClick={openFilterPanel} />
            </div>

            {openFilter && <SidebarFilterPanel categories={categories} />}
          </div>
          <div className="grid gap-4 lg:grid-cols-4 sm:grid-cols-2 grid-cols-1 place-items-center mr-auto ml-auto w-full mt-4">
            {products &&
              products?.map((product) => (
                <Products key={product.id} product={product} />
              ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Filters.js

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import Slider from "@mui/material/Slider";

import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
const Filters = ({categories}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div className=" w-[200px] shadow-lg h-[600px] flex flex-col px-2 py-10">
      <div className="w-[150px] ml-auto mr-auto flex flex-col gap-2">
        <p className="font-bold">Price</p>
        <Slider
          valueLabelDisplay="auto"
          aria-labelledby="range-slider"
          min={0}
          max={1500}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="px-2 mt-6">
        <p className="font-bold mb-2">Catogries</p>
        {categories.map((category, index) => (
          <p
            className="cursor-pointer text-sm my-2 hover:text-orange-500"
            key={index}
            // onClick={() => handleSelectCategory(category)}
          >
            {category}
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className="w-[150px] ml-auto mr-auto flex flex-col gap-2 my-8">
        <p className="font-bold">Discount</p>
        <Slider
          valueLabelDisplay="auto"
          aria-labelledby="range-slider"
          min={0}
          max={30}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="w-[150px] ml-auto mr-auto flex flex-col gap-2 mt-8">
        <p className="font-bold">Rating</p>
        <Slider

          valueLabelDisplay="auto"
          aria-labelledby="range-slider"
          min={0}
          max={5}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Filters;
```

Comment: Are you wanting to filter the `products` array? Where are you trying to filter it and what conditions do you want to filter by? Please include all relevant code as part of your [mcve].

Comment: I want in the productSLice file how to apply filters on products. This is the whole code for applying filter in the category, price

Comment: So you want to filter the `products` array by price? Where/how do you get the price value back out to `Home` so `products` can be filtered?

Comment: yes for example if I apply the price filter It shows me the filtered products on the home page.

Comment: Filtering `products` is trivial... once the min/max price filtering values are passed to the `Home` component. It doesn't appear as though any of the sliders in `Filter` actually do anything though.

Comment: I just wanted to know how to implement it in the redux toolkit.

Comment: Don't do it there, filter it inline when rendering. It's anti-pattern in React to store derived state. The redux store is the `products` array source of truth.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249340/discussion-between-pavitar-sharma-and-drew-reese).

Comment: If I use only ReactJS, It will work for me. But I don't know how to implement filter property by using redux-toolkit. Because I am using dispatch method for getting from the store. So, Kindly help me how to implement on the home page for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating another state slice to hold filter categories and their values. Consume the products array and the filter values and filter the products inline when rendering.

1. Create a filters slice and add to the store

   filter.slice.js

   ```js
   import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

   const filterSlice = createSlice({
     name: "filters",
     initialState: {
       price: 1500
     },
     reducers: {
       setPriceFilter: (state, action) => {
         state.price = Math.max(0, action.payload);
       }
     }
   });

   export const actions = {
     ...filterSlice.actions
   };

   export default filterSlice.reducer;
   ```

   store.js

   ```
   import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
   import productReducer from "./features/productSlice";
   import cartReducer from "./features/cartSlice";
   import filtersReducer from "./features/filter.slice";

   export const store = configureStore({
     reducer: {
       cart: cartReducer,
       filters: filtersReducer,
       product: productReducer
     }
   });
   ```
2. Update `Filter` component to consume the filter values and dispatch updates to the store.

   ```
   import React from "react";
   import Slider from "@mui/material/Slider";
   import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
   import { actions as filtersActions } from "../redux/features/filter.slice";

   const Filters = ({ categories }) => {
     const dispatch = useDispatch();
     const price = useSelector((state) => state.filters.price);

     return (
       <div className=" w-[200px] shadow-lg h-[600px] flex flex-col px-2 py-10">
         <div className="w-[150px] ml-auto mr-auto flex flex-col gap-2">
           <p className="font-bold">Price</p>
           <Slider
             valueLabelDisplay="auto"
             aria-labelledby="range-slider"
             min={0}
             max={1500}
             value={price}
             onChange={(e, value) =>
               dispatch(filtersActions.setPriceFilter(value))
             }
           />
         </div>

         ...
       </div>
     );
   };

   export default Filters;
   ```
3. Filter the `products` array inline when rendering in the `Home` component.

   ```
   const Home = () => {
     const dispatch = useDispatch();
     const { products, status } = useSelector((state) => state.product.products);
     const { price } = useSelector((state) => state.filters);

     const [openFilter, setOpenFilter] = useState(false);
     const openFilterPanel = () => setOpenFilter(!openFilter);

     useEffect(() => {
       dispatch(fetchProducts());
     }, []);

     useEffect(() => {
       document.title = "Shoping Website";
     }, []);

     return (
       <div>
         <div className="flex gap-4 justify-between px-4">
           <div className="hidden md:block">
             <Filters categories={categories} />
           </div>
           <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full">
             ...
             <div className="grid gap-4 lg:grid-cols-4 sm:grid-cols-2 grid-cols-1 place-items-center mr-auto ml-auto w-full mt-4">
               {products
                 ?.filter((product) => product.price <= price)
                 .map((product) => (
                   <Products key={product.id} product={product} />
                 ))}
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```

[image: Edit how-to-apply-filters-property-in-redux-toolkit-in-reactjs-projects#74325637]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Drew Reese for resolving this query.